# Can't write an input to stdin in a Java program via command line, although I can do it on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, windows-10

I wrote a Server-Client model program in java, and it works great on eclipse. However, when I try to run the client via command line (in Windows 10), I can't write anything to stdin (while I can do it on Eclipse). Why is that?
Here is the client code (not the best one, I know):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MyEchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Socket clientSocket = null; // the connection socket
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String host = args[0], msg, tmp;
        int port = Integer.decode(args[1]).intValue(), len;
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + host + ":" + port);

        try {  // Trying to connect to a socket and initialize an output stream
            clientSocket = new Socket(host, port); // host and port
            out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"), true);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
              System.out.println("Unknown host: " + host);
              System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get output to " + host + " connection");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try { // Initialize an input stream
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get input to " + host + " connection");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Connected to server!");

        BufferedReader userIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try{
            while(true){
                while(!userIn.ready()){
                    if (in.ready()){ // if server has something to write, when client does'nt have something to write
                        tmp=in.readLine();
                        len=tmp.length();
                        System.out.print(tmp);
                        if ((len>0 && tmp.charAt(tmp.length()-1)=='>') ||  tmp.contains("UNIDENTIFIED"))
                            System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
                msg = userIn.readLine();
                if (msg==null) { break; }
                out.println(msg);
                tmp=in.readLine();
                if (tmp.contains("~")) { break; }
                System.out.println(tmp);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){ System.out.println("Error with server connection."); }
        System.out.println("Exiting...");
        out.close();
        in.close();
        userIn.close();
        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Edit: this is the input I get when I try to run `MyEchoClient` with the command (after connecting to a server on port 4000) `java client.MyEchoClient 127.0.0.1 4000` :

```
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:4000
Connected to server!
```

(`MyEchoClient` is at folder named `client`).
And as I said, I can't write anything to stdin...

Comment: What is your command line call? Was there an output? Edit: I assume that "Connected to server!" was printed, and you can't input anything after that?

Comment: I just tested it on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. Compiled as always with "javac test.java" and run with "java test www.google.com 80". I could input a Message and the Google Server answer to it.

Comment: Mein Name- for your first response: I now edited my post. And yes, I can't input anything after "Connected to server!". For your second response: the program works on Linux, but I need it to work on Windows.

Comment: Yes since the program works on Linux, it should also work on Windows. For me the problem sounds like a Windows 10 command line problem, which isn't connected to your Java code. (Maybe someone else can test the program on theire Windows 10 System to find out wether it's a Windows 10 problem, or a problem with your System)

Comment: I'm suspicious of the use of `.ready()` for console input.